# What is C++/CLI required for?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Are there any tasks that require you to use C++/CLI and cannot be done in managed code (with P/Invoke and the `Marshal` class), performance aside?

Comment: Our company has a huge communication infrastructure entirely developed in native C++ that is used both by our  C++ code and by newer C# components. I find that C++/CLI is an incredibly useful tool to bridge legacy components with the .NET world. But I would not start a new project in C++/CLI just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, C++/CLI is *required* when you need to interop with libraries that were written in native C++.  Neither pinvoke nor Marshal can tackle templates or C++ classes with instance functions.  Or any functions that take a standard C++ library object as an argument like std::string, std::vector, etcetera.  Or use exceptions to report errors.

And it *may* be required to use a C library that has a clumsy interface.  One that fumbles memory management, requiring the caller to release memory for example.  Or uses excessively intricate structs that are too difficult to reproduce in managed code.

COM interop could be an alternative, but that requires pretty substantial changes to the C++ library when it wasn't originally written to support COM clients.  Using C++/CLI is much simpler.

Comment: *One that fumbles memory management* classical case: if you need to call `free(...)` directly, then you probably need C++/CLI

Comment: My knowledge of C++ may not be high enough, but can't instance functions be called with the instance pointer as the first argument (and possibly ThisCall)?

Comment: Only a C++ compiler can ever figure out what the correct value of *this* might be.  C++'s support for multiple inheritance is the great randomizer.  You might have a shot at it, still doesn't solve the problem of calling the constructor and destructor correctly and properly allocating and releasing memory for the object.

Comment: Hmm, that's nonsensical,  extern "C" is one you *don't* need.  And always better to not use, the mangled name reliably causes a binding error when the function changed, an excellent diagnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Well first, C++/CLI IS managed code.

While you could use C#/VB.NET with P/Invoke to accomplish most things you could do in C++/CLI, C++/CLI just makes it easier to mix managed code and unmanaged code in one place. For example, it's easier to include Windows.h or any other C++ API compared to having to repeat the declarations in C# and having to figure out how to marshal each parameter and return value.

It's also required in cases where you're using a library or any piece of code that uses C++ classes, as you can't P/Invoke those due to name mangling and other issues. This is one of the most common use of C++/CLI nowadays: to interoperate between native C++ and C#/VB.NET.

Comment: This would be clearer if you pointed out that Win32 is a C API (can be called using p/invoke, although C++/CLI makes it easier) vs real C++ APIs (classes, templates, overloaded names, virtual function tables where the names aren't even exported, etc) which as you note are not compatible with p/invoke.